# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider Caused by: java.lang.Class

Tags: java, spring

I am getting this error when I run my App As a Spring Boot App in Eclipse IDE:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider
    at org.mayo.eis.IMoveApplication.main(IMoveApplication.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 1 more
```

Running Springframework version: 3.2.3